# Will installing Rubymine cause any conflicts with my existing OS X configuration?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rubymine

In the past, I've done all my Rails development with a simple text editor, and have setup virtual Linux machines on my MacBook so I didn't have to worry about messing up OS X's native Ruby installation. Now I am leaning towards giving Rubymine a shot. I've been trying it out on a Windows platform and I like it enough to want to try it on my main development machine.

I'm a little apprehensive about installing it - will it compromise my system's default Ruby installation at all? Is it easily (and completely) uninstalled if I decide to change my mind later?

If anyone has any experience with Rubymine on OS X and can let me know about any potential conflicts or issues, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used it for over a year--it does nothing environmentally damaging. It detects and uses Rubies already on your system.

I don't do any Ruby development without it, because I jump between Windows/Linux/Mac, and can have the same hotkey behavior with all that syntax highlighting, refactoring, and debugging.  There is nothing better than being able to step into a gem that's acting up...

Comment: Thanks for the assurance! I'll give it a shot, it has taken me a little effort to get used to running an IDE for Rails, but I am quickly learning to love it!